# SQL Management Studio filter Where Value "Does Not Exist"?

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, not-exists

I joined two tables (let's call them Hours and Target) and want to pull a target from the second table if the there is a target associated within a time period that surrounds the date in Hours. (Target may have something like this: User:Joe, Target:70, From:1/1/2012, To:5/31/2012"

So far this was easy:

I joined 'All of' Hours with Target based on "user", I output Target and use 'From' and 'To' with a filter: "<=Hours.Date" and ">=Hours.Date", respectively.

The problem is that not all users may have targets in any time frame. In that case I would like to have a target of 0 returned. Based on the conditions, however, Lines that do not match my criteria above are not returned at all.

How can I set up a condition that returns something like this:

Target.Target where (Target.From <= Hours.Date and Target.To >= Hours.Date)
 or 
0 in all other cases

Thank You!

Marco

Comment: This would be a lot easier if we had a sample dataset or at least table structure and queries to work with instead of some abstract textual description of what you want.

Comment: Do you just need a `LEFT JOIN` and a coalesce on your column definition in your query?

Answer (score 1):

Are you after something like this?
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/18b5c/1/0

Ideally you would have a users table and store ID's but my understanding of what you have asked this should cover what your trying to do.